# Update a field of an existing instance

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-4

I'd like to update a field in an instance of an entity using a numeric value. All the examples I've seen (such as [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151183.aspx)) are based on the paradigm of retrieving the instance, altering it and then storing in the DB. That's seems inefficient and the code looks nasty and unnecessarily long.

Is there a shorter way to update an entity?

I have the following data:

- the name as *String* (one being *lead*, the other being *new_holder*)
- the guid as *Guid*
- the value as *int*
- the field name as "String"

So, I've tried to start like so.

```
DynamicEntity entity = new DynamicEntity("new_holder");
TargetUpdateDynamic update = new TargetUpdateDynamic();
update.Entity=entity;
```

The problem is that I'm not certain how to act around the data to be stored.

1. Should I *Add()* as properties? Or just write into the bag?

   ```
   entity.Properties.Add(...);  
   entity["field name"] = ...;
   ```
2. How do I treat the identity? Do I really need to use that long syntax?

   ```
   Guid guid = ...;  
   Lookup lookup = new Lookup("new_holder", guid);
   LookupProperty lookupProperty = new LookupProperty("id", lookup);
   entity.Properties.Add(lookupProperty);
   ```
3. Am I assuming the correct **type** when declaring the lookup?

   ```
   Lookup lookup1 = new Lookup("lead", guid1);  
   Lookup lookup2 = new Lookup("new_holder", guid2);
   ```
4. Am I assuming the correct **field name** when declaring the lookup property? Or should I use *new_holderid*, *holder_guid* or anything else other than just *id*?

   ```
   LookupProperty lookupProperty = new LookupProperty("id", lookup);
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to retrieve the entity first if you already have the Guid of the record.

I don't have a CRM 4.0 environment to test but:

1) If you want to assign a value to a property it is not necessary to check (and add) the property first, just write:

```
entity["field name"] = ...;
```

but I'm not sure if this works also for the primary id field

2) The identity isn't a `Lookup` type but a `Key` type, so if your entity is `new_holder` the id field is `new_holderid`:

```
entity["new_holderid"] = new Key(guid);
```

because I can't check if this syntax works, you can always write:

```
entity.Properties.Add(new KeyProperty("new_holderid", new Key(guid)));
```

3) If you want to assign an `int` you need to use `CrmNumber`:

```
entity["fieldname"] = new CrmNumber(5);
```

Full example:

```
DynamicEntity entity = new DynamicEntity("new_holder");
entity.Properties.Add(new KeyProperty("new_holderid", new Key(guid)));
entity["field name"] = new CrmNumber(5);
TargetUpdateDynamic update = new TargetUpdateDynamic();
update.Entity = entity;
UpdateRequest request = new UpdateRequest();
request.Target = update;
UpdateResponse response = (UpdateResponse)service.Execute(request);
```

As I wrote before I don't have a CRM 4.0 instance, but you can try the code and check which syntax works

Comment: Awesome, G! I'll give it a whack at work tomorrow and then check it as the correct answer. And if all of that actually work straight off, I think you also deserve some bounty. Let me get back to you.

Comment: I can't bounty you for some reason. The link doesn't appear on my screen... :(

Comment: @KonradViltersten don't worry, the important is that you solved :)